# how to add mime type to data url

Tags: javascript, mime-types

How can I add mime type to data url, for example

> Ex: `data:image/jpeg,http://google.com/images/abc.jpg`

In fact I have the images url to which I am appending `data:image/jpeg` otherwise  am only able to download the image as abc.txt (server defaulting to text) on anchor/link click using download attribute.

I have no access to server's `Content-Disposition` headers and the images url is hosted internally so heroku cors proxy is unable to access the images file server.

When I add data:image/jpeg to url, I am able to download the file with my own name but there is no content on the file, if i do not use any `data:` stuff I am able to get the file correctly but filename is different from what is mentioned in the download attribute.

I therefore want to know how to correctly set url so I can download the file with my own name accordingly.

**EDIT:**
Adding relevant Javascript I use to download file

```
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.download = file_name;
link.target="_blank";
link.href = url;
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
document.body.removeChild(link);
delete link;
```

The google image url is just an example but it actually is a local file server, the filename can be any name I specify.

Comment: `data:image/jpeg,http://google.com/images/abc.jpg` - that is not a real data URI to begin with ... it makes about as much sense as sawing a fish and a car together.

Comment: Data after the comma are supposed to be actual content of the dataURI document - for images binary stream encoded into base64 representation.
I guess you should also provide more detail about the way you initiate the download at the client…

Comment: @myf, ofcourse it needs to be in binary representation, but for now I have only the url, how to  get it into binary at all at this moment.

Comment: @CBroe, Added more information, please look into it, and thanks for your comment, I wanted to represent my issue in simple manner, yes, the url needs to be in binary and for now I only have the url, also other ways of downloading the file from Url are either erroring in the file content or file name

Comment: You have a real problem (getting the image to the browser) which you are ignoring to deal with a fake problem (convincing the browser to think that a piece of text (the URL to the image) is the image. (While this is technically possible, it is pointless, because the end result will still be a text file and not an image!). You need to focus on actually getting the image to the browser before worrying about what you want the browser to do with it then.

Comment: You will only be able to get to the data “behind” such a URL via JavaScript, if you can either request it from the same domain, or it is CORS enabled. Then you could do an AJAX request to get the actual image data, and assemble the correct Data URI from that.

Comment: @Quentin, Normally, on anchor click, I have the image downloading with only the extension as txt instead of jpg and file name as stored in server, if i rename the extension, I am able to view the image as is,  which I believe is because the server is defaulting to text mime-type

Comment: @CBroe, Is there anyway I can set CORS on client side, because the CORS Proxy is not effective on my local image file server url (10.X.X.X),  I however have no access to the local server to set any properties at server side

Comment: _“Is there anyway I can set CORS on client side”_ - if you need this only for yourself, then you can use a browser extension that disables those CORS restrictions. For general visitors of your site that is of course not possible - it would negate the sense behind the SOP and CORS, if you could specify that from the client side.